# Upgraded to .NET 4.0 & getting Could not load file or assembly reference to old version of DLL that was removed

Tags: c#, .net, reference

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'FOO, Version=1.0.3975.20137, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2aec35e026e7fee4' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>   File name: 'FOO, Version=1.0.3975.20137

I have a C# program that we constantly update and it gets reinstalled and it seems that since I've upgraded the project from VS2005 to VS2010 and .NET from 2.0 to 4.0 I'm getting this strange error where its trying to reference the old version of the dll from the last install.

When I go to the directory where its installed Prorgam Files(x86)/.... the latest version of the DLL is in there.  In the code there are no references to the old DLL.  The only way to fix this is to uninstall the program manually and reinstall.  After that the program works fine.

I am lost and confused as to why it would want to keep referencing an old DLL version when its not even there.   I have tried running fuslogvw.exe but it hasnt yielded any useful information.  I also thought it was possibly the setup project to I deleted and recreated one from scratch.  I've also done the usual clean solution & rebuilding.  I've searched all thru the forums and online but most people seem to have a problem where the old version of their DLL is still in the program directory and the new DLL didnt get installed.  My problem is the opposite.

Comment: You'll need to make Fuslogvw.exe work for you.  Log all binds and don't forget to click Refresh.  Also document whether you got a new machine as well.  And the Platform target setting for your EXE project.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this error appear when the Clean action for some reason forgets to remove all the dlls in my project's bin directory, and I've had to manually delete those dlls. You might want to check that all the relevant dlls are getting removed as part of the update process. I'm guessing that's what happens when the program gets uninstalled, which is why it works then.

Comment: It's definitely clearing it out and the new version of the DLL is in there.  I've checked multiple times. Its trying to reference an old dll that has been updated

Answer (score 0):

I would start with Who deployed the last breaking version.

It's possible that their machine incorrectly references a bad / old version, whether in the GAC or a hangover from a BIN directory.  Also, you mention reinstalling "manually"..  Does this mean that you have some build server or other deployment automation in place?  It's possible the assembly reference is being picked up by it.

Basically, you'll need to track down exactly how the bad app is being deployed to that machine and fix it.

Comment: its not a machine issue.  Its a program/deployment problem.  I've seen this issue experienced across multiple machines.  When I say manually reinstalled.  I mean by going to add remove programs and uninstalling it from there.  Then rerunning the setup.exe install.  Normally i just run the new setup file and the uninstall old version property is set to true and it does it automatically.  But I've tested it to where i uninstall an old version then manually install the new version.  It seems like the only way to get it to work correctly is to install it twice.

Comment: @user517761: Ahh, I get it.  You know, I've run into something similar to this before.  The only difference appears to be that we were installing services.  It didn't happen all the time, but it appeared to happen on certain machine configurations (XP, certain SP levels..).  We didn't bother tracking it down and instead just made it standard procedure to do an uninstall, reboot, install.  I wonder if the setup program is jacked somehow for certain OS's.

Comment: I've deleted the setup project and created a new one.  And the problem is the same across win xp 32 bit and win 7 64 bit.  Its been pretty fustrating.